# Tensor Serving Container - Error Too many open files

Tags: tensorflow-serving

After adding new models to the tensor serving container , after some time it is throwing below `error`

> tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:369]
>   FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a file-system access error:
>   /; Too many open  files

What is the way to stop getting this `error`

Comment: Do you have more info on how to solve this or what was the root cause?

Comment: The issue stopped occurring but could not find the root cause for it

Comment: I am getting the same error intermittently. Which version of tf serving and grpc (at client) are you using?

Comment: Please provide the versions being used for tensorflow serving and GRPC(client).
Please try with the latest versions and check.